# When/how do I write Apps scripts in Dart

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to create apps script using Dart and the Dart->JS translator?

I'm guessing the answer is no, but I'd be interested in learning of any plans to integrate the two development environments.

Comment: Did we have further information?

Answer (score 1):

You guessed right, the answer is no indeed. You can't write Apps Scripts in Dart.

Although your second question can only be answered by a Googler, but as a Top Contributor, I can say that if such plans exist they're probably not for the near future. I'd guess that it will not be here within a year.

Google Apps Script have a very specific set of libraries and usage that I imagine not to be Dart's team goal. I think such integration does not have much "appeal" for either teams (Apps Script and Dart).

Answer (score 1):

A Googler has shown in [DartConf 2018 lightning talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S0fEqbrIiBM) for using Dart in App Script. He promised it will be open sourced. The demonstrated solution includes App Script library in Dart, automated build and deployment through Google Drive.